# CUDA/GPU not being utilized

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, whisper

I am basically trying use pyannote.audio for diarization and then use Whisper for transcriptioning.
I have two machines One with RTX3050 Laptop GPU, Other is my desktop with 2060 Super. Issue is when I am running my code on Laptop (RTX 3050) GPU is utilized 80-100 % but when I am running the same code on my desktop it is not being utilized.
While following on both machines gives me True
`torch.cuda.is_available()`
And I am even trying to enforce my GPU on both machine using this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") // gives cuda
model  = whisper.load_model(model_size, device=device)
result = model.transcribe(audio=audiof, language=lang, word_timestamps=True)
```

Configuration for both is:
Laptop :

1. Nvidia cuda toolkit installed
2. cuda version = 11.7
3. torch installed version

```
torch                     2.0.1+cu117
torch-audiomentations     0.11.0
torch-pitch-shift         1.2.4
torchaudio                2.0.2+cu117
torchmetrics              0.11.4
torchvision               0.15.2+cu117
```

4. Whisper and pyannote versions:

```
openai                    0.27.8
openai-whisper            20230314
pyannote.audio            2.1.1
pyannote.core             5.0.0
pyannote.database         5.0.1
pyannote.metrics          3.2.1
pyannote.pipeline         2.3
```

Desktop :

1. Nvidia cuda toolkit installed
2. cuda version = 11.8
3. torch installed version

```
torch                     2.0.1+cu118
torch-audiomentations     0.11.0
torch-pitch-shift         1.2.4
torchaudio                2.0.2+cu118
torchmetrics              0.11.4
torchvision               0.15.2+cu118
```

4. Whisper and pyannote versions:

```
openai                    0.27.8
openai-whisper            20230314
pyannote.audio            2.1.1
pyannote.core             5.0.0
pyannote.database         5.0.1
pyannote.metrics          3.2.1
pyannote.pipeline         2.3
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I am still new to using torch but I have tried all the solutions so far